# How to resolve AttributeError error while using prophet?

Tags: python, prophet

I have even used this command conda install -c conda-forge prophet and even tried to pip uninstall pystan, prophet and installed again. But, still facing this issue.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-70a8fe714d7e> in <module>
----> 1 model = Prophet()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py in __init__(self, growth, changepoints, n_changepoints, changepoint_range, yearly_seasonality, weekly_seasonality, daily_seasonality, holidays, seasonality_mode, seasonality_prior_scale, holidays_prior_scale, changepoint_prior_scale, mcmc_samples, interval_width, uncertainty_samples, stan_backend)
    139         self.fit_kwargs = {}
    140         self.validate_inputs()
--> 141         self._load_stan_backend(stan_backend)
    142 
    143     def _load_stan_backend(self, stan_backend):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py in _load_stan_backend(self, stan_backend)
    152             self.stan_backend = StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(stan_backend)()
    153 
--> 154         logger.debug("Loaded stan backend: %s", self.stan_backend.get_type())
    155 
    156     def validate_inputs(self):

AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'
```

Comment: Always Google your errors before posting.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are installing latest version of `pystan` which is not supported yet by `prophet`. You need to do `pip install pystan==2.19.1.1` or `conda install -c conda-forge pystan=2.19.1.1` and then install `prophet`.

See [prophet installation instructions](https://github.com/facebook/prophet#installation-in-python) and [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1574) for more reference on your issue.

Comment: That third "this" was a bit much :) Aside from that, nice find

Answer (score 0):

I have been going through the same issue, even after installing `pystan=2.19.1.1` and then installing `prophet`. But my issue was resolved with the following steps.

1. use `CMDSTANPY` as stan_backend. Reference [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2153)
2. Install cmdstn using this reference [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/main/README.md)
3. Install the following commands(centos)

   ```
   yum install gcc gcc-c++ make wget ca-certificates tar gzip -y
   wget --progress=dot:mega https://github.com/stan-dev/cmdstan/releases/download/v2.27.0/cmdstan-2.27.0.tar.gz
   tar -zxvf cmdstan-2.27.0.tar.gz
   ln -s cmdstan-2.27.0 cmdstan
   cd cmdstan; make build
   cd cmdstan; echo "CmdStan home directory is" $PWD
   CMDSTAN=/var/task/cmdstan STAN_BACKEND=CMDSTANPY pip install prophet
   ```

Now you will be able to run Prophet properly without any errors. I hope this answer helps everyone who is struggling with this issue.